# JPA EntityManager discover entities from other bundle (OSGI)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, osgi-bundle

In an OSGI environment such as Equinox, i want to have 2 bundles (or more bundles) and each one has his own JPA annoted entities (classes). I want to have a dependency between the classes from each bundle.

*For example:* 
I have bundle 1 with the class Person and bundle 2 with the class Employee which extends Person (this is most simple example i can think of - i know i could declare the both classes in one bundle but i need them to be in separate bundles).

Is it possible to expose an EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory as an OSGI service which knows about the entities present in both bundles? I know that each bundle can have his own EntityManager(EM) but in the given example the EM in bundle 2 doesn't know about the entity Person. If is possible can anyone give an example or sugest how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have a dependency between the classes from each bundle.

This is not possible when using Equinox + OSGI. The nearest you can achieve using unmodified Equinox and Gemini JPA is using composite persistence units, but that still requires that your entities are in the same bundle but in separate JARs.

I've created a hack using a patched Gemini JPA bundle that can dynamically create a composite peristence context by merging persistence contexts across bundles, but it's extremely hairy and finicky; it has dependencies on bundle loading order and it will not react properly to bundle reloads, hence mooting half the purpose of OSGi...

OTOH, you *can* expose separate entity managers and use them both in both bundles as long as you accept that there will be a short period of time where only one of them will be available. Nothing prevents you in Bundle B tracking the EntityManager of Bundle A (well, except cyclic bundle dependencies, but that happens oly if you cross-import packages).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried Gemini JPA and Composite Persistence Units, looked in Hibernate docs but it seems i didn't find a solution and thought to ask here to see if anyone found one (or tried what i need to do). Is hard to believe this is not possible though...

Comment: It's hard because one does get transitive dependencies that make edge cases non-trivial: consider the case where bundle A is exporting PU B; bundle C expecting persistence unit A. If now a new bundle D has an extension of PU B, then C has to indirectly depend on D too or else queries can return classes that C doen't have access to. Also, if one dynamically de-installs D, then A and C need to be refreshed...

Comment: Just had an epiphany: try making D a fragment bundle attaching to the original bundle A, along with [Configuration Admin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Gemini/JPA/Documentation/OtherTopics#Configuration_Admin) dynamic configurations; in all probability you will need to enumerate all your entities...

Comment: Hmm... that i didn't try so far. I will try and let you know the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Why should this not work? If Employee extends Person then bundle 2 will import the package that contains Person. So it has a dependency to bundle1 1. In the persistence.xml of bundle 2 you should be able to list both Employee and Person. So both work in the Entitymanager of bundle 2. Of course the EntityManager of bundle 1 can not know about Employee.

Comment: Well, i've tried that and EntityManager of bundle 2 doesn't recognize the entity Person from bundle 1. I can extend the class Person as bundle 2 knows about it after i added bundle 1 as a dependency so i am not getting an error before running the code. In persistence.xml of bundle 2 only Employee is known as an entity, while Person is unknown entity.

Comment: How does your persitence.xml looks like?